# How to get File from the assets folder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

This is my below code. I'm trying to fetch the file from the assets folder which is placed in my local Package. But everytime it is showing like File Not Found.

```
    final String cachePath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    
    const String targetPath =
        "packages/local_wifi_manager_old/assets/ota/salus/firmware/SAU2AG1_ZC.tar.gz";

    final File destinationFile =
        File("$cachePath/SAU2AG1_ZC.tar.gz");

    try {
      final File sourceFile = File(targetPath);
      if (!sourceFile.existsSync()) {
        print("File not found");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      LoggerService().e(e);
    }
```

What I want to do is copy file from the source destination (which is assets) and copy it into destination folder.

**What I have tried? :-**

- I have tried using rootbundle as well. By using rootbundle method it is showing "too large" error while coping the file. That's why I'm not using that code.
- Other way I tried is to use File.copy() option but using File path is getting. Don't know what's the issue there.

Comment: is `local_wifi_manager_old` your Flutter project name that you're working on?

Comment: You need to load the asset into memory and then write it out. See linked question.

Comment: @sm_sayedi local_wifi_manager_old is my package name... which is created by me.